# spring can't receive post param send by postman

Tags: spring-boot, http-post, postman

[image]

And My Controller is like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/company/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseMessage deleteCompany(@RequestParam("companyId") Integer companyId) {
    return companyManageService.deleteCompany(companyId);
}
```

But when I type code in chrome console using

```
$.post( "http://ltc_dev.leapstack.cn/gw/security/auth/company/delete", { companyId: 1 })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( data.success);
    alert( data.message);
  });
```

I got correct response, so.....
I'm not sure if it is a postman's bug, or I cofig the controller wrong

Comment: It is not requestParam you are sending via postman. It is the requestBody. If you want to send it as request param your url should be **/auth/company/delete?companyId=2**

Comment: @barbakini even I changed #RequestParam to #RequestBody It still not working, and I tried to change companyId from Integer to String with #RequestBody and got value as "companyId":2 instead if 2 !

Comment: Did you try as ** /auth/company/delete?companyId=2** ?
And if changing requestBody, your method should get a Map object not a String or Integer. like **deleteCompany(@RequestBody Map body)**
body.get("candidateId)

Comment: I want to use integer receive a json string in post request

Comment: You should read some about what is a json string and how it is cast to java type. Your json string in your question is **{"companyId":2}** and as you can see, it cannot be cast integer directly(Because it non-numeric 
 string value ). You can wrap it into a class which has a property **int companyId** and spring will auto cat in into your controller method or like I said above, it can be cast a map which has one element whose **key** is companyId and **value** is 2. I will post an answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

In your question, your controller method try to take **companyId** as request param. In postman you are sending companyId in request body. Like I said in comment you can send request param in url section directly like that: **/auth/company/delete?companyId=2**. Spring boot can detect companyId request parameter and assign it to method's companyId variable directly.

If you want to send companyId in request body (You said that in comment) you have to change your method's signature like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/company/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseMessage deleteCompany(@RequestBody Map<String, Integer> map) {
    return companyManageService.deleteCompany(map.get("companyId"));
}
```

Or:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/company/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseMessage deleteCompany(@RequestBody CompanyDTO company) {
    return companyManageService.deleteCompany(company.getCompanyId);
}

public class CompanyDTO {
    private Integer companyId;

//getter setter
}
```

If you want to use request body and want to catch integer value directly in controller method's variable as integer your request body should be like:

```
{2}
```

And controller method should be like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/company/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseMessage deleteCompany(@RequestBody Integer companyId) {
    return companyManageService.deleteCompany(companyId);
}
```